# How to replace a printed line in Python 3

Tags: python

I am trying to make a sort of stop watch thing, just to try and learn some different stuff.

The problem is that I don't know how to make it so when you print what the time is, it just replaces what time you currently have printed.

For example if the time was:

H M S:
0 0 1

I would want it to display

H M S:
0 0 2

Without having to print a new line, so it would look like it is just counting up so to speak. I've it doing this in a way by printing new lines but it still shows a sort of movement which makes it clear that there are new lines being printed.

Here is my code as it is now, feel free to run it and your get what I mean:
http://notepad.cc/woupodi42

Any ideas would be appreciated even better if they apply directly to this problem :)

Comment: i think that's what `\r` is for

Comment: Ive seen this being used but from what i can tell it dosent replace the line just adds to it, i could be mistaken though

Answer (score 8):

There is an overload of [print](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#print)() that will do this. Combine this with `[\r][2]` to move the cursor to the start of the line before writing each.:

```
import time
for x in range(10):
    print('\r H M S 0 0 ' + str(x), end='')
    time.sleep(1)
```

OR

```
for x in range(10):
    print('\r H M S 0 0 {}'.format(x), end='')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This dosent seem to actually replace the last printed line just adds to it?

Comment: Just prefix your line with '\r' to reset the cursor. I'll update my answer to show this.

Comment: Ive tried running that code and again it just seems to print on the same line but does not remove what has already been printed, i could just be being stupid though so could you perhaps put it into an example in some way?

Comment: It overwrites the current line for me. I'll update the code example with the exact code that I'm using to test with.

Comment: if i run that code the output i get is:

 H M S 0 0 0
 H M S 0 0 1
 H M S 0 0 2
 H M S 0 0 3
 H M S 0 0 4
 H M S 0 0 5
 H M S 0 0 6
 H M S 0 0 7
 H M S 0 0 8
 H M S 0 0 9

where as it should only display one thing at a time like a digital clock

Comment: Interesting, I get each line overwritten with the last, such that in the end I get just " H M S 0 0 9". What OS are you running? And what minor version of Python 3?

Comment: python 3.3 on windows 7

Comment: Hm, same as me. Does it work after introducing a brief sleep() call, as in the code above?

Comment: Tried as well, same for me, everything is on a new line.

Answer (score 4):

Use the end parameter to specify a "\r" as the line ending.

```
for x in range(10):
    print('\r H M S 0 0 ' + str(x), end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint for you, you need sys.stdout.write with `\r`:

```
import sys, time
>>> for x in range(10):
...     sys.stdout.write('%d\r' % x)
...     sys.stdout.flush()
...     time.sleep(1)
...
```